# I can't see correct style of a specific website

Tags: google-chrome, browser, to-do

I use `Google Chrome` as web browser. I haven't problem with this browser. I using `Astrid` website and android client as `To-Do List` program.
I have a problem ONLY with [astrid web site](http://astrid.com), it is don't show correct style of website and I can't see image and etc, I see only text. Others website work fine and only this site (and important for me) don't work fine.
I tested this web site with others browser such as `Microsoft IE` and `Mozila Firefox` but get same result.

I show this website home page in following:

[image]

Comment: Try disabling all Chrome extensions or view the site in Incognito mode. If it looks ok, that means some extension is to blame. Else try accessing it via a proxy.

Comment: I remove all extension of my chrome and now chrome's extension page shows `Boo... You have no extensions :-( Want to browse the gallery instead?` message but yet don't correct my problem. Also I try by Incognito mode but don't correct website style. I'm looking for a web proxy that test with it.

Comment: I tested `Astrid.com` website but yet get previous style :(

Comment: My means was: I tested `Astrid.com` website by a proxy server but yet getting previous style :(

Comment: That's weird. If something's blocking images, CSS etc. (since all browsers at your end are displaying the same thing), then a proxy *should* have fixed it. Can you go to `Windows\System32\drivers\etc`, open the **hosts** file with Notepad and copy-paste the contents above or in [PasteBin](http://pastebin.com)?